# TortoiseHg HTTP Error: 500 when cloning or pushing repositories

Tags: mercurial, debian, tortoisehg, digital-ocean

Whenever I try to clone or push my repos i would receive the following error message:

```
realm: Mercurial Repository
HTTP Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)
[command returned code 255 Sat Apr  9 18:21:26 2016]
```

One workaround would be to reboot my server, however the error would appear on the next clone/push. 
What could be the root of this issue and how do i resolve it?